# How to model table in order to query large amounts of dependent data

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

I have many log records in the following format

```
a_id, b_id, c_id, count, x_id, y_id, z_id
```

The object relations are as follows

```
a has_many b
b has_many c
c has_many y
y has_many z
```

I am looking to run the following queries, what database (relational or anything) structure would enable to model/run these queries against a large volume of data.

```
find count for a certain a_id
find count for a certain a_id and set of associated b_id(s)
find count for a set of a_id(s) and set of associated b_id(s)
find count for a certain a_id, b_id and set of associated c_id(s)
find count for a certain a_id, set of b_id(s) and set of associated c_id(s)

find count for a certain x_id
find count for a certain x_id and set of associated y_id(s)
...
```

Comment: I think any conventional database software would suffice...are you asking for a specific design implementation?

Comment: how should I design, should it be in a single relational table (which will have millions of rows) or should it be in a specialized database which is not relational.

Comment: If counting is the only operation and if the above relation is going to be the primary relation, then MySQL should be easy ad efficient for such a database. However NoSQL would be useful if the data size is huge and lot of joins are required. But the best idea would be, try both and determine which one works best. Each of these technologies is specifically built to handle different kinds of real-world scenarios. So try both. All the best.